# Ribbon colour reversed

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having issue while drawing a graph with ribbons. I came across a sample script in a thread here. That has the same problem.

Below is the script from the thread (slightly modified)

```
x=1:10
y1=1:10
y2=2:11
y3=10:1
y4=9:0

dt=data.frame(x,y1,y2,y3,y4)

library(ggplot2)  

g<-ggplot(dt)+
  geom_ribbon(aes(x=x,ymin=y1,ymax=y2,fill='red'),
              alpha=0.4)

g<-g + geom_ribbon(aes(x=x,ymin=y3,ymax=y4,fill='blue'),
              alpha=0.5)

g<-g +  scale_fill_manual(name='legendname',
                    values=c('red','blue'),
                    labels=c('one','two'))
```

The script draws two ribbons called "one" and "two". Ribbon "one" (going up) is supposed to be red and "two" (going down) is supposed to be blue. But the colours are reversed.

If the script is executed step by step you will see that the ribbon one gets drawn as red first and when ribbon two gets drawn it changes colour.

I am totally new to R. So explain to me what is happening here?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [ggplot2 documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/ggplot2.pdf) (p.10), when you set the argument `fill` in the aesthetic, you're basically creating a color scale (could be either continuous or discrete, depending on the argument). I'm not sure about the internal implementation of the aes function, but I'm suspecting that since you're passing it a color string, instead of a vector of possible values, the fill argument is simply ignored.

In fact, if you view `g` before you apply the `scale_fill_manual` function, you'll see that ggplot2 assigns its default colors to the ribbons, instead of the colors that you selected:

[image]

And the reason why the colors are reversed at the end is because when you apply the `scale_fill_manual`, the color red goes to the layer on top, and the color blue goes to the layer below it.

To get the colors right, what you can do is assign the `fill` argument to `geom_ribbon` instead of `aes`, as follows:

```
g <- ggplot(dt)
g <- g + geom_ribbon(aes(x=x, ymin=y1, ymax=y2), fill = 'red', alpha=0.4)
g <- g + geom_ribbon(aes(x=x, ymin=y3, ymax=y4), fill = 'blue', alpha=0.5)
```

Also, you don't need the color scale at the end for this particular example.

Comment: _the fill argument is simply ignored_ Not exactly, note that the fill scale (and the legend for it) is created only if fill goes into `aes`. In your example, the legend is missing. The explanation itself is correct though, the order in this particular example is defined by the appearance of layers, not the `ggplot` call syntax.

Comment: It is ignored in the sense that it's not utilized in determining the color of the ribbon in this particular example. But you're right, if you want to keep the legend, then you can change the order of the colors in the `values` argument to correspond to the reverse order of the layers (i.e., first argument goes to top layer, last argument goes to bottom layer).